# Facebook JS SDK throwing 104 error when attempting to delete a app request

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have setup the facebook javascript sdk to initialize a friend invite dialog to send requests to friends.  Clicking on the invite in Facebook, brings the user back to the site.

The query string has any and all request_ids that have not been handled (deleted).

I am following the documenation listed at the FB developers site [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting) which states:

***JavaScript SDK:***
    FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {

When they are returned to my site, the querystring has a **request_ids** parameter:

**example:** www.mysite.com/somepage?request_ids=0493834050

my Javascript code looks like this:

```
FB.api(requestIds[i], 'delete', function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
```

But the error I get is:

**ERROR**

code: 104

message: "An access token is required to request this resource."

type: "OAuthException"

All I want to do is delete the request ID.  before I was even running the above code, the querystring was building up with every submitted request.  It does appear they have been removed, because the querystring is reduced down to a single request id.  But I am still uncertain it has been handled properly.

**NOTE**  I am not using the Graph version - as I have not setup Graph on the app settings in Facebook.

I have the Facebook C# sdk - if someone has an easy way to do this here.  I have tried the following with the same results.

```
var fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken)
fbClient.Delete(requestId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see what’s possibly unclear about the error message – you need a valid access token to be able to delete requests, but by the looks of it you don’t have one.

So you’ll either have to have the user connect to your app in order to get an active access token for him; or you have to do it using your own app access token (but that’d have to be done server-side then, because you don’t want to transfer your app access token to the client side).

Comment: Unfortunately, I must disagree, it is not clear that you need an access token according to their own documentation.  The error might say as much (thus the reason for the posting) - but unless I am using the Graph API (which I am not), I don't see where it is outlining that I have to retrieve the users access token or utilize mine for the JS SDK api.

Comment: To me it __is__ clear that you need an access token – a) from the message you are getting, and b) from just thinking about it for a moment using a little bit of common sense: If it would __not__ require an access token to delete requests, then nothing would stop me from just firing HTTP requests at Facebook’s servers going through any number of possible `<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>` combinations hoping for random hits and thereby deleting request for other people’s apps. (I wouldn’t even need an app myself for that, since I can fire HTTP requests from anywhere.)